# How to move a program from a partition to another one?

Tags: virtualbox, encryption, directory, partitioning

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu, so sorry in advance if this is a noob question, but I don't know how to solve this situation.

I've installed Virtual Box on Ubuntu, and I've also installed Truecrypt (That I Had used to create an Hidden encrypted Volume on the Hard Disk). Now, I want to move the program VirtualBox (That is installed on the partition not encrypted of the Hard Disk) to the partition encrypted with Truecrypt (The Hidden Volume).

I've searched for the Vitual Box folder or similar, where is installed the program, but is not like in windows or OSX where you only have to find the program and then you can move it wherever you want; in fact there is not just a folder for the program, but more than one. (For example I have in Usr/bin these files : Vbox, vboxautostart, vboxballoonctrl, xbox headless, vboxmanage, vboxsdl, vboxtunctl, vboxVRDP and vboxwebsrv; and then there is a folder called Virtualbox in Usr/lib).

I don't know, probably I have to move the folder that is Usr/lib to the Encrypted Partition, or not?

Thanks in advance for any answer :)

Comment: Hmmm....what advantage do you have moving programming with no security revelent information to an encrypted crypt disk?  What is the real problem here?

Comment: The aim is probably that nobody could know that he has VB installed. 

You can't move programs so easily in Windows. Most will also install things to the Windows folders and add values to the (non-encrypted) registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. IMO it is easiest to mount your truecrypt partition to /usr/local and "install" vbox and the libs there.

You can manually copy vbox to /usr/local (/usr/local/bin , /usr/local/lib , etc) or compile vbox from source using the option PREFIX=/usr/local , then install.

You then need to make sure /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib is on your path.

Modify these directions if you choose an alternate mount point.

Probably easier to keep vbox installed in the default location and when making a guest, place the guest virtual hard drive on your encrypted partition.